# Create Toeplitz Matrix from vector data

Tags: c#, matrix

Does anyone know of a fast and efficient C# code to create:

1. a rectangular N x N Toeplitz matrix given a vector of data?
2. create an N x M Toeplitz matrix given two vectors of data; one for the first row and one for the first column?

Right now it looks like a lot of looping but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the response but I fail to see how that document helps at all.

Comment: it shows you how to make a array and add data to it with out looping

Comment: The point here is to create a Toeplitz array not just any kind of array. I am aware of how to create and populate an array.

Comment: What is your current algorithm, and what is its efficiency?

Comment: @PBrenek .net does not have a Toeplitz array class, you need to look to something like MathWorks for that functionality. To a .net developer it is just another array or table that needs to be filled with data.

Answer (score 0):

With Matlab use the function toeplitz ;)
(toeplitz --help)

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about how to use the function (specifically addressing the asker's question)? What version of MATLAB or what toolbox did this become available in?